# download file with progress bar

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar, download

I did the program ,following this turtorial:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/

All is OK but I have two questions.

When the application starts downloading the file, appears ProgressDialog. So it is OK. But when
I click on screen ProgressDialog disappears.
Is the possible add button 'Cancel' on ProgessDialog and block screen.
When user click Cancel , downloading should be break and
 ProgressDialog should disappear only if:
-user click Cancel button
-Downloading sucessful

Answer (score 0):

When you click on Screen, Progress Dialog dismisses because of this - `pDialog.setCancelable(true);` You should check its API for details - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html.

Now, To add button, there is no direct way, so you will need to create your custom `ProgressDialog` by extending `AlertDialog`. There's an example below -

[create progress dialog with another layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196879/create-progress-dialog-with-another-layout)

Also, you would like to check - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog.